# How to recuperate the date of last Actualisation of a request toward a extern data source?

Tags: excel, vba, request, datasource, powerquery

In my excel file I have a request (using Power Query) toward a SharePoint list.
This request generate a table in my file.

You can actualize the request here :

[image]

And here you can see the last actualisation date :

[image]

I want to use VBA to recuperate this date in a cell.

I put this VBA code in my Sheet "Données Brutes" where the table of my query is, and I run sub test:

```
Private Sub RecupDateActua(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
dateString = Format(Target.RefreshDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Range("M1") = dateString
End Sub
 
Public Sub test()
    Call RecupDateActua(Sheets("Données Brutes").PivotTables("Rondes__2"))
End Sub
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: is datetime Value "16:41" ? what you want to be.. ?

Comment: Hi Sacru2red, 16:41 was the hour of the last actualisation when took the screenshot, I juste want to have it whatever its value is